# Perform SUM() Calc with Where Statement then Insert SUM() Into another SELECT Statement with different FILTERS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to SUM 12 columns together with a specific WHERE Statement to filter the data so the numbers are correct, and then I have to try to inject the results of that SUM into my main table for the report.

Below is some code I am working with and testing (its still very rough and I am building it one step at a time), but I attempted to use CREATE VIEW in order to get my SUM Results and I attempted to get that into my main SELECT Statement for the report but it wasn't working correctly at all so I abandoned that and just commented out the Create View block. But hopefully this gives a good idea of my overall plan is in my head.

There are other columns I will likely have to calculate the same way, so I'm trying to figure out the best way I can chain this all together in a simple but effective way.

End goal is a report in SSRS to compile 401k info.

```
/*
GO
CREATE VIEW [TOTAL CONTRIBUTIONS] AS
SELECT SUM(MTDWAGES_1 + MTDWAGES_2 + MTDWAGES_3 + MTDWAGES_4 + MTDWAGES_5 + MTDWAGES_6 + MTDWAGES_7 + MTDWAGES_8 + MTDWAGES_9 + MTDWAGES_10 + MTDWAGES_11 + MTDWAGES_12) AS 'TOT CONTRI'
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[UPR30301]
WHERE PYRLRTYP LIKE '3' AND PAYROLCD LIKE '401K';
GO*/


SELECT A.EMPLOYID, LASTNAME, FRSTNAME, SOCSCNUM,BRTHDATE,STRTDATE,DEMPINAC AS 'Term Date', B.YEAR1,
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[UPR00100] A
INNER JOIN [DB1].[dbo].[UPR30301] B ON A.EMPLOYID = B.EMPLOYID
INNER JOIN [DB1].[dbo].[UPR30300] c ON A.EMPLOYID = C.EMPLOYID
--WHERE 
GROUP BY A.EMPLOYID, LASTNAME, FRSTNAME, SOCSCNUM, BRTHDATE, STRTDATE, DEMPINAC, B.YEAR1, B.PYRLRTYP, B.PAYROLCD
```

Comment: Kudos on the step-by-step.   Always a good approach.   Just a quick concern:  Any of the MTDWAGES_n  NULL  because n+NULL = NULL

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out by using TEMP tables with my parameters and calculations then inner joining those temp tables and inserting columns from those. Thank you though, I am still learning a lot about SQL :)

Answer (score 1):

Your MTDWages data is unnormlized, but I'm guessing that you know that and are not in a position to change that. However, you can use a `CROSS APPLY(SELECT VALUES ...)` to make it look normalized after which you can use built-in aggregation functions.

Something like:

```
SELECT A.EMPLOYID, LASTNAME, FRSTNAME, SOCSCNUM, BRTHDATE,
       STRTDATE, DEMPINAC AS 'Term Date', B.YEAR1,
       SUM(W.MTDWAGES) AS [TOT CONTRI]
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[UPR00100] A
INNER JOIN [DB1].[dbo].[UPR30301] B ON A.EMPLOYID = B.EMPLOYID
INNER JOIN [DB1].[dbo].[UPR30300] c ON A.EMPLOYID = C.EMPLOYID
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
        (B.MTDWAGES_1), (B.MTDWAGES_2), (B.MTDWAGES_3), (B.MTDWAGES_4), 
        (B.MTDWAGES_5), (B.MTDWAGES_6), (B.MTDWAGES_7), (B.MTDWAGES_8), 
        (B.MTDWAGES_9), (B.MTDWAGES_10), (B.MTDWAGES_11), (B.MTDWAGES_12) 
) W(MTDWAGES)
--WHERE 
GROUP BY A.EMPLOYID, LASTNAME, FRSTNAME, SOCSCNUM, BRTHDATE, STRTDATE, DEMPINAC, B.YEAR1, B.PYRLRTYP, B.PAYROLCD
```

If needed, you can also add a key:

```
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
        (1, B.MTDWAGES_1), (2, B.MTDWAGES_2), (3, B.MTDWAGES_3), (4, B.MTDWAGES_4), 
        (5, B.MTDWAGES_5), (6, B.MTDWAGES_6), (7, B.MTDWAGES_7), (8, B.MTDWAGES_8), 
        (9, B.MTDWAGES_9), (10, B.MTDWAGES_10), (11, B.MTDWAGES_11), (12, B.MTDWAGES_12) 
) W(Month, MTDWAGES)
```

Comment: I ended up figuring it out by using TEMP tables with my parameters and calculations then inner joining those temp tables and inserting columns from those. Thank you for your help though, I tried the cross apply method and it did work but the values weren't correct because it didn't allow me to use the correct filtering. 

Thank you though, I am still learning a lot about SQL :)